# Whom does this statue to the left of the cordonata leading up to Piazza del Campidoglio depict?

Tags: sculpture

I was in Rome last week. There's a couple of mysteries I need help solving, and this is one of them. The statue looks like this:

[image]

It stands modestly to the left of the cordonata and you might even miss it when you ascend towards the plaza.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google image search eventually led [here](http://Cola%20di%20Rienzo).

> Cola di Rienzo (or de Rienzi; Italian pronunciation: [ˌkɔːla di
>   ˈrjɛnt͜so] or [de ˈrjɛnt͜si]) (c. 1313 – 8 October 1354) was an
>   Italian medieval politician and popular leader, tribune of the Roman
>   people in the mid-14th century.